# Don't show a file as modified (only stage on explicit add)

Tags: git

Is it possible to keep a certain file from showing up as modified, even though it is, effectively only allowing it to be pushed to the remote after explicitly adding it with `git add`?

My scenario is this:

I've got documentation on GitHub in the `/docs` folder, and that documentation uses a bundled JavaScript file. This bundle uses the module that is being developed in the repo. I only want the documentation to have the latest published version available, i.e., I don't want to update the docs with every new commit.

What I've tried so far is to add the file to `.gitignore`, and use npm's `prepublish` script to bundle up the file and run `git add --force` on it. This, however, adds the file to git and causes subsequent edits to show it as modified.

I'm somewhat aware of `git update-index`, and I've used it very sparingly before, but from what I understand, that is used for the local index, and I need this file to be ignored for everyone, as soon as they clone the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect fancy magic from a version control system. Just reorganise the code and deployment work-flow. By default put docs into something like `/build/docs` (and put `/build` into `.gitignore`) then make a "deploy" script which copies `/build/docs` into `/docs` for publishing.